# How to make an activity as launcher activity at run time depending on screen orientation

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an app which starts differently according to device orientation (vertical or horizontal). For this i have two layout xml files but how to decide, which one to open as launcher activity depending on screen orientation of mobile.

Comment: i think fragment can help you. have you read about that?

Comment: sry! i have little knowledge about fragments . if you can give me an example or link to a example it would be easy for me to understand

Comment: as i think you need something that in portrait you have one page and in landscape have detail of that too, if you need this you can implement that via Fragments. like contact application that in portrait have one list of contact but in landscape details of contact is added beside list

Comment: I don't get you but is this what you are looking for?         'WindowManager windowManager=(WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);' 
        'display=windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();' and then calling display.getRotation();

Comment: So you want to open a different activity from the launcher depending on which orientation the device is in? (If so, why?)

Answer (score 2):

Put one layout in a the `layout` directory and the other in the `layout-land` directory (create this directory if it doesn't exist yet). Make sure both files have the same name. At runtime android will choose the one that best matches the configuration of the device.

See [Providing Alternate Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the current orientation and `setContentView` with the relevant xml file.

For example:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
   setContentView(R.layout.something_landscape)
}
else{
   setContentView(R.layout.something_portrait)
}
```